# String formatting of cell comments EPPLUS library

Tags: .net, excel, epplus

Is it possible to format the comments when creating a *.xlsx* file using EPPLUS?
As far as I know the only method is:

ExcelComment **AddComment**(string *Text*, string *Author*);

Are there other known limitation to comments with this library? 
If yes is there a better alternative in .net ?

Comment: What else do you need to do with comments which might not be supported? Afaik there is no alternative which doesn't require an office license.

Comment: I am having trouble with some comments which are being truncated (because too long i think).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out I was wrong in deciding prematurely that EPPLUS was limited

### Comment format

The **AddComment** method created the object and it returns it. This way you could edit the objects using *RichTextCollection* inside the *ExcelComment*

This example puts in **bold** a part of the cell comment:

```
ExcelComment commento = wItem.AddComment(null, "Sys");
commento.RichText.RemoveAt(0);
ExcelRichText ert = commento.RichText.Add(dataItem.Commento[0]);
ert.Bold = true;
ert = commento.RichText.Add(dataItem.Commento[1]);
ert.Bold = false;
```

### Truncation

As for the truncation it wasn't visible at first because of the dimension of the comment bubble.
[image: examplecomment]
Used Autofit property

```
wItem.Comment.AutoFit = true;
```